# ASP.NET Web API with Decorations on Models

Tags: ajax, asp.net-web-api, code-first

Technology Used: Code First,ASP.NET Web API (restful service) and HTML.

For code first I have a domain Object called User

```
public class User
{
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

And I have decorated the properties with [Required].

Then I have my MVC Web Api Post Method

```
    public string Post(Domain.User regModel)
    {
        return "saved";
    }
```

and lastly I have my Ajax Call

```
var user = {
Id: "1",
Email: "test@test.com",
PasswordHash: "asjdlfkjals;dkjflkjsaldfjsdlkjfiovdfpoifjdsiojfoisj",
IsDeleted: true
};
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/api/registration/post',
cache: false,
data: JSON.stringify(user),
crossDomain: true,
contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",

success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

});

**Error As Requested**
POST http://localhost.com:11001/api/registration/post 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
 <Error>
    <script/>
    <Message>
    The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
    </Message>
    </Error>
```

**My Problem**
If I decorate my Model with [Required] I get an Error `500 - No Get Method Supported`
however if I remove that. Everything works well.

I just really want to understand why this is the case with MVC Web API. sure I can create view models but. I just want to understand why this is happening.

Can someone please explain

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the exact error message? Which controller does not support Get method it says?

Comment: added. its on registration controller. I do have a get method on that but what  is confusing me is the Decorations on the domain object. cos this works when I comment them out.

Comment: Though the way you have modeled the API is slightly non-standard, that should not be a problem. Everything here looks ok. Did you try going to Web API source code?

Comment: I don't even hit a breakpoint on the web api if I decorate it. what do you mean "try going to Web API source code?"

Comment: I mean the source code for `ASP.NET MVC` which can be found here http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have found a reason why abit late as I already changed from a web api to a standard MVC. (which works perfectly no work around to be done) you can find the answer in the following links:

[asp net web api validation with data annotations](http://sixgun.wordpress.com/2012/03/28/asp-net-web-api-validation-with-data-annotations/)

[web api nullable required property requires datamember attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633974/web-api-nullable-required-property-requires-datamember-attribute)

[dataannotation for required property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305784/dataannotation-for-required-property)

Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

Could the problem actually be that you are trying to Post a user with `Id = "1"` while `Domain.User` specifies that Id is of type Guid. A "1" does not make a valid Guid, so when that property is marked with `Required` it can't make the call to your `Post` method. When you remove the required attribute, the `Post` method can be used/called, because it will just set the Id of the User object to Null or an empty Guid, as it is not required.