# Web API - how to make value type parameters in a complex object required

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm wondering what the best practice is for making value type parameters (DateTime, int, etc) required with Web API.

According to [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api), I should make the property nullable and use the Required attribute.  Doing so results in the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633974/web-api-nullable-required-property-requires-datamember-attribute).  Following the advice in that SO question and using `[DataMember(IsRequired=true)]` seems to work, but the error messages returned in ModelState is not as helpful as using the Required attribute.  Furthermore, I need to deal with a nullable type in the controller which we know will never be null since it passes the model validation.

I've seen people describe this as a bug and also have seen that it may be resolved in Web API 2.  Is there any truth to this?

Comment: Have you looked at `FluentValidation` it has a `NotEmpty` validation that considers the default value of value types to be invalid. It can be used standalone or there is a extension that hooks it up to Web API validation.

Comment: I haven't yet, but I will now.  My initial concern, without actually trying the code first, is what happens if you actually want to pass in zero for an int.  NotEmpty would fail because zero is the default for int?

Comment: You will never be able to work around that though; how is ASP.NET supposed to know when you mean "0" and when you mean "empty"? That's why the nullable approach exists: to remove ambiguity.

Comment: Fair enough.  So, assuming the nullable approach, do I need to do the DataMember IsRequired thing?  Using just Required attribute does not seem to work.  Then, as I mentioned, the error you get back when you use DataMember IsRequired is rather ugly.