# DataAnnotation for Required property - Why is it required for asp.net webapi?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, data-annotations, datacontract

I read through these posts

[DataAnnotation for Required property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305784/dataannotation-for-required-property)

http://forums.asp.net/t/1835627.aspx/1

and I understand it has something to do with `xml` and not supporting `required` but I don't get why this is an issue.

I have a `View Model` that has a `Required` attribute over a `Guid` and that is what is causing the problem. I just don't get how the xml factors into this as the `request` is `REST` so where does the xml come in play to cause this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The validator was added as a security measure because all Web APIs accept XML by default. And because the XML formatter doesn't raise model state errors for missing required members, you could end up in a situation where a required member was missing and yet the model state was valid.

With that said, this behavior has caused a lot more trouble than it's worth. So it is gone in the current nightly builds, and it won't be there in the next version of Web API. In the meantime, you can disable it with this line:

```
config.Services.RemoveAll(typeof(System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatorProvider),v => v is InvalidModelValidatorProvider);
```

Comment: Hmm. So should I use data contracts for Required or what is the best way to go about it now. I am having alot of trouble with xml(was about to post another issue with it)

Comment: If you really need the property to be required, then you should use data contract attributes and [DataMeber(IsRequired=true)]. If you're OK with no error being raised if the member is missing in XML though, you could always just use the line above.