# POST controller value is always NULL

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-4.5, asp.net-web-api2

Firstly thank you for taking the time out to read this post.

I've been building my first asp.net 4.5 MVC4 Web Api, but the value received in the controll POST method is always NULL.

To test the POST api method I've tried Fiddler and Google Chrome Simple REST Clinet but the result is always the same.

Here's my code:

**Controller (POST)**

```
    // POST api/Terminal
    public HttpResponseMessage PostTerminal(Terminal terminal)
    {
        if (terminal == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, terminal);
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Terminals.Add(terminal);
            db.SaveChanges();

            HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, terminal);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Url.Link("DefaultApi", new { id = terminal.Id }));
            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
        }
    }
```

**Model Class**

```
    public class Terminal
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int TerminalId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime TagDate { get; set; }
    }
```

In the above code, the value received in the POST method **terminal** is always NULL.

Here's the command I've been using to POST using Fiddler:

**Method:**
POST

**Address:**

```
http://localhost:52036/api/terminal
```

**Header:**

```
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:52036
Content-Length: 60
```

**Body:**

```
{"TerminalId":123,"Tag":"222","TagDate":2014-04-13 04:22:12}
```

**----------- EDIT - 13-04-2014 14:56 -------------**

I have modified my Fiddler http post request as advised to in some of the replies to this question with the following details. However I keep getting a 500 HTTP error and my API code doesn't even reach the Controller when testing in VS2013 debug mode.

**Address**

```
POST
http://localhost:52036/api/terminal/
```

**Header**

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:52036
Content-Length: 62
```

**Body**

```
{"TerminalId":123,"Tag":"222","TagDate":"2014-04-13 04:22:12"}
```

**-------------- Edit 13/04/2014 20:38 -----------------**

Ok, using Google's Chrome REST Client, I've noticed the following return error message:

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Property
>   'TerminalId' on type 'ClockingDemo.Models.Terminal' is invalid.
>   Value-typed properties marked as [Required] must also be marked with
>   [DataMember(IsRequired=true)] to be recognized as required. Consider
>   attributing the declaring type with [DataContract] and the property
>   with
>   [DataMember(IsRequired=true)].","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.Validators.ErrorModelValidator.Validate(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, Object container)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ShallowValidate(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateProperties(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata
>   metadata, ValidationContext validationContext, Object container)\r\n
>   at
>   System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.Validate(Object
>   model, Type type, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider,
>   HttpActionContext actionContext, String keyPrefix)\r\n   at
>   System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Object
>   model)\r\n   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass36`1.<>c__DisplayClass38.<Then>b__35()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass49.<ToAsyncVoidTask>b__48()\r\n
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1
>   func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

I think the problem is coming from the fact that my **INTEGER** property **TerminalId** is defined as **[Required]**. I have a feeling there might be an issue with setting a non-NULLABLE property and **[Required]**.

Very much open to suggestions.

**----------------- ANSWER ---------------**

I finally stumbled across this thread which solved the problem for me.
[DataAnnotation for Required property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305784/dataannotation-for-required-property)

Simply paste this into the Global.asax file:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.RemoveAll(
    typeof(System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatorProvider),
    v => v is InvalidModelValidatorProvider);
```

I'm still open to other solutions if you believe there is a better method.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Noted. (Should I say thanks for pointing this out?)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 0):

In Fiddler you have to use like below

Your Request Body should like this **{"TerminalId":123,"Tag":"222","TagDate":"2014-04-13 04:22:12"}**
and in your request header you need to pass content type like this **Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8**

Comment: Unfortunately this still doesn't work @Naveen. I keep receiving a 500 error. When running my API in debug mode the code doesn't even get to the controller to stop at my break point. See my original question, I have posted an edit with your suggested modification.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have a hybrid ASP.NET Web Forms with MVC and Web API.

Just solved like this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostTerminal(JObject jsonMessage) 
{
        var terminal = jsonMessage.ToObject<Terminal>();
        if (terminal == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, terminal);
        }

        ...
    }
```

References: http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/May/08/Passing-multiple-POST-parameters-to-Web-API-Controller-Methods