# Required attribute on action parameter doesn't work

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api

The code is like:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public ResultEntityVM Register([FromBody,Required] RegisterParam createAssessorParam)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid == false)
    {
        return null;
    }

    //other code
    ResultEntityVM vm = new ResultEntityVM();
    return vm;
}
```

When the parameter `createAssessorParam` is `null`, the value of `ModelState.IsValid` is `true`. Why?

If I want to auto judge the parameter is `null` or not, what can I do?
Don't I can only write the code:

```cs
if(RegisterParam  != null)
{
   //other
}
```

Comment: `Required` attribute on `Properties` are more valid.But then too,you run into trouble.see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305784/dataannotation-for-required-property

Comment: Because the property is value type.

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same problem and solved it by implementing a custom action filter attribute evaluating all the validation attributes of the action method parameters.

I described the approach in [this blog post](http://blog.markvincze.com/how-to-validate-action-parameters-with-dataannotation-attributes/), where I use ASP.NET Core 1.0, but the same approach should work with ASP.NET 4 as well.

Comment: The blog is a bit wrong. You need to replace the line of `var argument = ...` with `var argument = context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(parameter.Name) ? context.ActionArguments[parameter.Name] : null;`. Also, you can have this auto-applied to all endpoints by going to your `Startup`, finding `AddMvc()` and doing a `options.Filters.Add(new ValidateActionParametersAttribute());` in there. This will add some overhead to all endpoints, though.

Answer (score 1):

here is @MarkVincze's answer adjusted for asp.net web

```cs
public class ValidateModelStateAttribute : System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute 
// there are two ActionFilterAttribute, one for MVC and another one for REST
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Called before the action method is invoked
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext context)
    {
        var parameters = context.ActionDescriptor.GetParameters();
        foreach (var p in parameters)
        {
            if (context.ActionArguments.ContainsKey(p.ParameterName))
                Validate(p, context.ActionArguments[p.ParameterName], context.ModelState);
        }

        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Response = context.Request.CreateResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                context.ModelState.Select(_ => new { Parameter = _.Key, Errors = _.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage ?? e.Exception.Message) }),
                context.ControllerContext.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter
            ); 
        }
    }

    private void Validate(HttpParameterDescriptor p, object argument, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
    {
        var attributes = p.GetCustomAttributes<ValidationAttribute>();
        foreach (var attr in attributes)
        {
            if (!attr.IsValid(argument))
                modelState.AddModelError(p.ParameterName, attr.FormatErrorMessage(p.ParameterName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

In WebAPI, an action parameter will never be null. It is always instantiated by the framework. So you would rather use the `Required` attribute on the properties of your view model if you want to ensure that they are present.

Comment: If you post nothing,the parameter must be null.
I kown the attribute can used on properties.But if you see the  Required attribute definition,it can userd on parameter.

Comment: If you design your Web API so that it accepts only JSON you cannot POST nothing. Your request will be dropped much earlier than reaching your method. So basically you will need to POST some valid JSON.

Comment: I design the action  accepts only JSON exactly.But if I post nothing,the parameter is initialized null by .net,and the action is execute also.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov this is not true, at least in ASP.NET Core 1.0. If you have a parameter with the `FromBody` attribute, and you POST an empty body, the value of the argument will be `null`, and `ModelState.IsValid` will return true.