# Required attribute in action methods argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, data-annotations

I have an action method `Create` of a `Controller` as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Required]string name)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        IdentityResult result = await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(name));
        if (result.Succeeded)
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        else
            Errors(result);
    }
    return View(name);
}
```

What does the `[Required]` attribute do here in argument?

Comment: Please look the below url  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31892333/required-attribute-on-action-parameter-doesnt-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Required]` attribute allows you to use `ModelState.IsValid` construct.

Basically it says that your model is invalid when the marked parameter is null.

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: If you use the newerAPiController Attribute on the class of the controller, you do not need the modelstate.isvalid - it is done for you

Answer (score 0):

The `[Required]` ensures the model is validated. You get the below error if you ignore to send name as query string.

```
{
"name": [
    "The name field is required."
]
}
```